# Zookeeper Quorum and the Non- Quorum

Tags: apache-zookeeper, quorum

Zookeeper Experts.

The question that I am asking might be basic to you, but I am new to ZK, and I haven't mastered the tool yet so forgive me.  With that in mind here is my question.

Suppose I have a ZK Cluster of 5 Servers, and I have a quorum of 3.  Now this guarantees that the servers won't go into split-brain scenarios, if they are located into two physically separate DC or machines right.

However, what I want to know is if the Quorum is set to three it means that the Leader server, will need to wait until at least 2 server replicate the written data, total of 3 replicated data.   But what if a client connects to the server that is not part of the Quorum any of the 2 servers,  isn't  that means it gets the old data ?

Comment: Typically, you don't deploy ZK in two physically separate DCs due to network latency between them. For example, a single cluster across US and Europe wouldn't work very well

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot "set" the quorum. It is automatically calculated from the configuration, using `N/2+1` (the majority) where N is the number of zookeeper server *.

A Zookeeper server that is not part of a Quorum become unavailable and cannot server data to clients so no risk of seeing old data.

Comment: Sure, if the quorum is calculated, then you could potentially have an even number of servers resulting in split-brain, i.e 4 server quorum  = 2,  

And if I understand your answer correctly, are you saying that during the replication process, the nodes not-part-of-the-quorum they become unavailable ? 

But whaI about the Watch mechanism in ZK, shouldn't the not-part-of-the-quorum make use of it, or is only reserved for nodes in the quorum ?

Comment: Quorum cannot be an even number. I've updated the post to not use `ceil` but instead `+1` to clarify but both are the same. Yes you understood correctly, when not in a quorum, ZK nodes are not available. Not sure I understand your last question

Comment: I also recommend going over http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/zookeeperInternals.html as I think it covers your questions very well.

Comment: Thanks, Mickael,  It's beginning to make sense now.  Except for one thing.  I understand my question is vague. 

A cluster of ZK Nodes of 5 = Ensemble 
And the 3 Nodes are = Quorum

When a client send a write operation, to the master, then you have to have the three Quorum, up-and-runnning in order to write the data.

But what if a client reads from the non Quorum, which means the data is outdated ? Because the data is not propagated to the remaining two, which are not part of the Quorum.

How is this handled ?